# Is it a good idea to have multiple NHibernate EventListeners?

Tags: nhibernate

We are just starting out with NHibernate and have been looking at the NH Cookbook 3.0 which highlights using an EventListener for stamping an object with who created an object and when, then who changed an object and when.  We are now looking at implementing an audit tracker event listener (creating a history of property value changes).   Is it considered best practise to have two (or more) event listeners each handling one task, or a single eventlistener handling multiple tasks.

So the single event listener code would look something like:

```
public class EventListener : IPreInsertEventListener, IPreUpdateEventListener
{
    ...
    ...
    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent e)
    {
        _stamper.Update(e.Entity as IStampedEntity, e.OldState, e.State, e.Persister);
        _auditTracker.Update(e.Entity as IAuditTrackedEntity, e.OldState, e.State, e.Persister);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whilst the two event listener model would be something like:

```
public class StamperEventListener : IPreInsertEventListener, IPreUpdateEventListener
{
    ...
    ...
    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent e)
    {
        _stamper.Update(e.Entity as IStampedEntity, e.OldState, e.State, e.Persister);
        return false;
    }
}

public class AuditHistoryEventListener : IPreUpdateEventListener
{
    ...
    ...
    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent e)
    {
        _auditTracker.Update(e.Entity as IAuditTrackedEntity, e.OldState, e.State, e.Persister);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which is considered best practise and are there any performance drawbacks to either?  The later (two separate event listeners) would seem like the best implementation for both clarify and maintenance, but just unsure if it's going to cause us problems later on.

Comment: Just as a quick update, as well as the stamper recommended in the NH 3.0 Cookbook, we've added a full audit tracker using the model referenced in this blog article: http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/08/31/auditing-with-nhibernate-listeners/.  Hence the reason for the two event listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with the separate implementation even for maintainability reasons - I have been using this approach in a couple of latest projects without any issues.. Who knows maybe at some point in the future you'll want to provide specific behavior in one of the listeners - in this case you would just re-point your configuration to the new listener/implementation without affecting existing code. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks, backs up my thinking too.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, there shouldn't be a noticeable performance impact, so I'd favor a separate event listener for each concern.

That would help with maintainability, testability, reuse, etc.